# How can I make a code that can print text of off a website and put it into a txt file

Tags: printing-web-page

Hi so I am trying to make a line of code that will print any information of off a specific website whenever I run it. I am having trouble finding which type of language I should use and how I would do this. Any help is appreaciated. I am new to coding so I'm sorry if I sound very dumb.

Comment: It depends on the website, but most of the time it's python.

Comment: Do you also know any ways of doing this?